# Is it possible to experimentally show that observable universe is much larger than ~93B ly?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

Thought experiment:

1. Entangle a pair of particles.
2. Package one half of each pair in a special package, and send it out in a nano-spaceship
3. keep the other half of the pair of entangled particles here on earth
4. accelerate nano-spaceship to 99.99999999999999% of the speed of light using a number of [tiny cyclotrons](https://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/devices/engineers-unveil-particle-accelerator-on-a-chip)

Due to Lorentz [contraction](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1224059837),

$$
L = L _\text{0} \sqrt {1 - \frac {v^{2}}{c^{2}}}
$$

In one years time, the spaceship would have traveled 93B ly away from us (in the spaceships relative frame)

After one year of travel, the spaceship could be preconfigured to detect the CMB in the direction of travel, and then trigger their quantum entangled particle to send a '0' or a '1' depending on whether the CMB was detected.

Repeat this process using any number of spaceships in any number of directions, and soon you would experimentally show how big the universe really is.

Any problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger their quantum entangled particle to send a '0' or '1'"? You can't send information using quantum entanglement, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem

Comment: Lorentz contraction wouldn't really work that way; as far as modern physics is concerned, nothing can move away faster than the speed of light _except_ due to space itself expanding, which tends to be a negligible effect at this scale.  Though this question might be rephrased a bit to ask about communication through quantum entanglement (quantum teleportation) outside of one's lightcone.  (Or did you mean 1-year's time, as perceived by the ship?)

Comment: Oh crap @enumaris... why have I never heard of the No-communication theorem?  Gahhhh no one knows the depth of my s u f f e r i n g.

Comment: And yes @Nat I mean 1-year's time as perceived by the ship.  I guess the No-communication theorem trumps everything anyway.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how Lorenz contraction works: after one year, your spacecraft would be *one* light-year from us. That's much less than one year as perceived by the people in the ship, but since they are never coming back their perceptions are not so interesting to us.

Furthermore, the [no-communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem) means that quantum entanglement can't send information in the way you describe. Once they are $d$ light-years away, traveling at speed $v=c(1-\epsilon)$, to communicate with them requires sending a signal ahead at $c$. That signal doesn't catch up to them for $d/\epsilon$ years, at which point their distance is now increased to $d\left( 1+\frac1\epsilon\right)$ light-years, and so their return signal will take even longer to reach us.

That furthermore assumes a flat spacetime, which is approximately correct for our universe locally but is more and more broken as you start to reach cosmological distances. Our universe is expanding, and its expansion is accelerating. There are currently galaxies which are being carried away from us by the expansion of the universe at a rate faster than the speed of light within spacetime, or for which their recession speed will exceed $c$ at some point before a signal sent now would reach them. Those galaxies are beyond our "communication horizon": no signal sent from Earth now will never reach them, including your spacecraft. Most of the volume of the universe is already beyond the communication horizon. (I have a nice source for this result that I will have to add to this answer later.)

So no, it wouldn't work. Your plan to send a space probe to investigate the cosmic microwave background (or rather, the galaxies which have formed at those distances whose light has not yet reached us) is flawed in its use of special relativity and quantum mechanics, and in its failure to consider cosmology.